# Javascript flip animation without jQuery

Tags: javascript, animation

Does anyone know if there is a Javascript flip animation around, similar to this one: http://lab.smashup.it/flip/, but that does not use jQuery.

I Googled before posting this question, but they seem all to use jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

see: http://www.scripts.com/viewscript/book-flip-slideshow/3626/

It is a free one.